# Is there a default output-directory for TensorFlow training batchjobs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, batch-processing, tensor

Lately, I'm trying to implement a training-service for TensorFlow.

I wasn't able to find any information regarding a output-directory for training-jobs in the documentation.

Is there any default-dir that TensorFlow uses (I'm really not familiar with TensorFlow at all)?

I was also thinking about the possibility that the output-dir can (maybe) be coded into a training-script or even be specified in the application-call via CLI.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: SO is not a great tutorial site, and these feel like questions that can be answered with some research and a stab at tensor tutorials. What research have you done?

Comment: Thing is: I'm pretty unsure where to start searching. without a proper description of a problem, it's pretty hard to find the right answers. I was searching in the Tensorflow documentation, but anything about training was not mentioning anything about the output of the training.

Comment: Since you say that you aren't familiar with tensorflow at all, that is where you ought to start, probably. This site is not a great place for answers that aren't about specific coding examples. The idea is you show your research. For example, https://blog.floydhub.com/teaching-my-robot-with-tensorflow/ was easily found, and it refers to an output directory as a result of a tweak to a Tensor supplied Python file. The idea is you probably need to circle back on your toolset, because general use questions don't get much traction here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an [`Estimator` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), the default output_directory is specified through `model_dir` argument. If you don't specify one, a temporary dir is created for you. See docstring:

> model_dir: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to continue training a previously saved model. If PathLike object, the path will be resolved. If None, the model_dir in config will be used if set. If both are set, they must be same. If both are None, a temporary directory will be used.